# django-select2 store multiple selection

Tags: django, django-views, django-select2

What is the correct way of saving multiple selections selected from Django-select2 Widget?

this is my model

```
class Rgn_Details(models.Model):

    request_no = models.ForeignKey(Request_Flow, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='request_ref')
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='regn')

    class Meta:
        ordering= ['-region']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region
```

I have a model form like this.

```
class RegionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    region = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Region.objects.all().order_by('region_id'),
                                            widget=Select2MultipleWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Rgn_Details
        fields = ['region']
```

this is my view

```
def create(request):

    if  request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = RequestForm(request.POST, prefix="form1")
        form2 = RegionForm(request.POST, prefix="form2")


        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            req = form1.save()
            region = form2.save(commit=False)
            region.request_no = req 
            region.save()
```

if I try `region.save()` its not working though form validation have no errors...

I am getting

> `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'region_id', table 'rgn_details'`

Am I doing something wrong with save method when you have multiple selections with Django-Select2 widget?

Comment: What's the value you are getting in `RegionForm`? I think you are not getting the desired value in that

Comment: Yes I am seeing values at form2.cleaned_data
<QuerySet [<Region: Southeast>]>

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used to store multiple data selected in the form....

not sure any built in solution available but this is working for me..

```
for _region in form2.cleaned_data['region']:
            region = Rgn_Details(region=_region, request_no=req)
            region.save()
```

Since I am not utilizing the feature of ModelForm I changed my form from ModelForm to regular Form

```
class RegionForm(forms.Form):
    region = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Region.objects.all().order_by('region_id'),
                                            widget=Select2MultipleWidget)

    class Meta:
        #model = Rgn_Details
        fields = ['region']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `commit=False` Django needs you to add `save_m2m()` as well.
So your code:

```
if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            req = form1.save()
            region = form2.save(commit=False)
            region.request_no = req 
            region.save()
```

should be instead:

```
if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            req = form1.save()
            region = form2.save(commit=False)
            region.request_no = req
            form2.save_m2m()
            region.save()
```

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/):

> Calling save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False). When you use a save() on a form, all data – including many-to-many data – is saved without the need for any additional method calls.